# MFA Multiple Verification Methods, change order of precedence

Tags: security, login, mfa

Salesforce has an order of precedence for verification methods when logging in with MFA:

1. Salesforce Authenticator.
2. Time-based one-time passcode (TOTP) authenticator apps.
3. Built-in authenticators.

How do i change this order of precedence.

Comment: can help link articles of what you've followed? and then update your question of what you tried

Comment: Man, what you mean what i tried. This is not about writing piece code, this is about where/if the functionality exists. What is there for me to try in it.

Comment: Out of the box - you can't. You can build your own login page and define your own order of precedence. The scenario where org users will have all 3 methods registered is quite rare in our experience.